# Save and restore cygwin session

Tags: windows, cygwin

I am looking for the way to save and restore cygwin session. For example, if it is saved, I can use the session file and start cygwin from the previous session where I left off.

P.S: Any way similar to Rstudio where session files are saved with one command and then loaded very easily.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: cygwin is a library layer, not a command interpreter. I assume you are looking for a bash (or other shell) behavior, but it is not clear what do you expect from the shell. Loading all the variables and the current working dir ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, loading data from previous session and current working dir.

Comment: Have a look at the shell built-in `define` command. IIRC it can display all env and shell vars and funcs in a format that you can save and execute to restore (most) state.